change the display name of a sharepoint list without breaking the associated powerapp and powerautomate
I am rewriting an integrated SharePoint list power automate to be a stand alone canvas power app.  and I have a link on the first column of the list that does a deep link and opens the power app with the correct id.  I used Sharegate to copy the structure of the existing list and named it mylistTemp.  now that I have everything working I would like to change the display name the users see on the list to mylist. but not break the PowerApps and my new Power Automate (leave the internal name as mylistTemp). can it be done?

Yes, you can change the display name of a SharePoint list without breaking the associated PowerApps and Power Automate flows since they reference the internal name. The internal name of the list, which is used in the backend, will remain as "mylistTemp," while you can update the display name to "mylist" for user visibility.
